# Determining all the processes started with a given executable in Linux

Tags: shell

I have this need to collect\log all the command lines that were used to start a process on my machine during the execution of a Perl script which happens to be a test automation script. This Perl script starts the executable in question (MySQL) multiple times with various command lines and I would like to inspect all of the command lines of those invocations. What would be the right way to do this? One possibility i see is run something like "ps -aux | grep mysqld | grep -v grep" in a loop in a shell script and capture the results in a file but then I would have to do some post processing on this and remove duplicates etc and I could possibly miss some process command lines because of timing issues. Is there a better way to achieve this.

Comment: Try `lsof /path/to/executable` (you may need to be root).

Answer (score 0):

Processing the ps output can always miss some processes. It will only capture the ones currently existing. The best way would be to modify the Perl script to log each command before or after it executes it.

If that's not an option, you can get the child pids of the perl script by running:

```
pgrep -P $pid -a
```

`-a` gives the full process command. `$pid` is the pid of the perl script. Then process just those.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `strace` to log calls to `execve`.

```
$ strace -f -o strace.out -e execve perl -e 'system("echo hello")'
hello

$ egrep ' = 0$' strace.out 
11232 execve("/usr/bin/perl", ["perl", "-e", "system(\"echo hello\")"], 0x7ffc6d8e3478 /* 55 vars */) = 0
11233 execve("/bin/echo", ["echo", "hello"], 0x55f388200cf0 /* 55 vars */) = 0
```

Note that `strace.out` will also show the failed execs (where `execve` returned -1), hence the `egrep` command to find the successful ones. A successful `execve` call does not return, but `strace` records it as if it returned 0.

Be aware that this is a relatively expensive solution because it is necessary to include the `-f` option (follow forks), as perl will be doing the exec call from forked subprocesses.  This is applied recursively, so it means that your MySQL executable will itself run through strace.  But for a one-off diagnostic test it might be acceptable.

Because of the need to use recursion, any exec calls done from your MySQL executable will also appear in the `strace.out`, and you will have to filter those out.  But the PID is shown for all calls, and if you were to log also any `fork` or `clone` calls (i.e. `strace -e execve,fork,clone`), you would see both the parent and child PIDs, in the form `<parent_pid> clone(......) = <child_pid>` so then you should hopefully then have enough information to reconstruct the process tree and decide which processes you are interested in.